# Memory monitoring on Heroku

Tags: django, memory, memory-management, heroku

We're running Django on Heroku, and I'm looking for a way to monitor how much memory is being used.  Once we go over our limit, we get errors that do tell us how much memory we are using, but I'd like to see how memory is ebbing and flowing even when we are under our limit.

It seems like basic functionality, but I haven't seen anything in the Heroku dyno docs that suggests a way to do it.  I'd really appreciate any pointers.

Thanks a lot!

Clay

Comment: Nearly 6 years later, it still seems that Django memory usage on Heroku is incredibly opaque and hard to measure. Any luck on this since 2012, Clay?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use Django on Heroku as well. The best way to monitor memory is to install the [NewRelic addon](https://addons.heroku.com/newrelic). When you first install it (the free version), you get a week of their 'advanced' usage tier free, which allows you to see all the stats about your application:

- Total requests per minute.
- Average response time.
- Slow pages.
- Database queries (response times, etc.).
- End user page load times.
- A variety of analytics.
- Background job stats (memory, cpu, etc.).
- Available RAM, RAM usage over time, etc.
- and lots more

For reference, here's a screenshot so you can see what I'm talking about:

[image: NewRelic memory stats]